# converting multiple lines of text into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to find a way to convert multiple lines of text into a
data frame.  I'm not sure if there's a way where you can use `read.delim()`
to read in multiple lines of text and create the following data frame
with something akin to `rehape()`?.

The data is structured as follows:

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 10
A: 34
B: 20
C: 6.7
A: 2
B: 78
C: 35
```

I'd like to convert this data to something that looks like the following data frame:

```
A             B             C
1             2             10
34            20            6.7
2             78            35
```

Apologies if there is an obvious way to do this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about :

```
s<-"A: 1
B: 2
C: 10
A: 34
B: 20
C: 6.7
A: 2
B: 78
C: 35
"
d<-read.delim(textConnection(s),header=FALSE,sep=":",strip.white=TRUE)
cols<-levels(d[,'V1'])
d<-data.frame(sapply(cols,function(x) {d['V2'][d['V1']==x]}, USE.NAMES=TRUE))
```

which yields:

```
   A  B    C
1  1  2 10.0
2 34 20  6.7
3  2 78 35.0
```

Comment: That was a clever use of `sapply()`.  I hadn't thought of using it that way before.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just starting to learn R, so I had to try using the few tools at my disposal. :) 
 I just noticed your solution using `unstack`. That looks like the best way to me.

Comment: Found this helpful because i needed to convert a text-string `"a;lorem\nb;ipsum\nc;gecko"` into a data.frame and it worked with the `textConnection()`-function I didn't know.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it with the plyr package:

```
require("plyr")
my.data <- "A: 1
            B: 2
            C: 10
            A: 34
            B: 20
            C: 6.7
            A: 2
            B: 78
            C: 35"   
df <- read.delim(textConnection(my.data),header=FALSE,sep=":",strip.white=TRUE)

as.data.frame(dlply(df,.(V1),function(x) x[[2]]))
```

You get

```
   A  B    C
1  1  2 10.0
2 34 20  6.7
3  2 78 35.0
```

You can see what magic plyr is doing just by playing with `dlply(df,.(V1))` or `dlply(df,.(V1),function(x) x)`

Comment: Thanks for the `plyr` suggestion.  Definitely worth exploring further.  I found an alternative to solving my question using `unstack`

Comment: Ah, good call; in this case that's probably the way to go.  plyr can be rather handy, though, for other "group by" type operations. If you'd like to explore further you might want to read http://had.co.nz/plyr/plyr-intro-090510.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I posted this question on R-help as well, and got a response from Phil Spector suggesting `unstack`.

This is a modification of Leo Alekseyev's response

```
my.data <- "A: 1
            B: 2
            C: 10
            A: 34
            B: 20
            C: 6.7
            A: 2
            B: 78
            C: 35"   
df <- read.delim(textConnection(my.data),header=FALSE,sep=":",strip.white=TRUE)
unstack(df, V2 ~ V1)
```

This results in:

```
   A  B    C
1  1  2 10.0
2 34 20  6.7
3  2 78 35.0
```

Some advantages of this approach compared to the other thoughtful answers is that you don't need to specify the number of columns ahead of time.  It also doesn't require any additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using reshape

```
s<-"A: 1
B: 2
C: 10
A: 34
B: 20
C: 6.7
A: 2
B: 78
C: 35
"
d<-d<-read.delim(textConnection(s),header=FALSE,sep=":",strip.white=TRUE)
N<-nrow(d)%/%3
d$id<-rep(1:N,each=3)
reshape(d,dir="wide",timevar="V1",idvar="id")
```

Which produces

```
  id V2.A V2.B V2.C
1  1    1    2 10.0
4  2   34   20  6.7
7  3    2   78 35.0
```