# Converting text file into dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to convert text file data in R. The dataset looks like this

```
RXID- 3233
OWN - NLM
AU  - HBGHB
AB  - good boy. 

RXID- 3234
OWN - NLM
AU  - HBGJI
AB  - bad boy.
```

I referred [converting multiple lines of text into a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391364/converting-multiple-lines-of-text-into-a-data-frame)  and  i did this

```
x<-read.delim("Test.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "-", strip.white = TRUE) #this is working well
cols<-levels(x[,'V1'])  #This is giving a null value
```

I am not able to find out why this is coming NULL

The final output should look like this

```
RXID   OWN   AU    AB
3233   NLM   HBGHB   good boy
3234   NLM   HBGJI   bad boy
```

Comment: That's because the code you copied was written 10 years ago when the default value for `stringsAsFactors` was TRUE. In the current version of R (4.0.0), this was changed to FALSE, so anything that looks like a character will remain as a character (unless you manually change the value to TRUE in the command to read the data). I'm assuming you are using R 4.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using R 4.0.0?

If you add "stringsAsFactors=TRUE" to your read.delim command, it should work.

```
x <- read.delim("Test.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "-", strip.white = TRUE,
                 stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

cols <- levels(x[,'V1']); cols
[1] "AB"   "AU"   "OWN"  "RXID"

d <- data.frame(sapply(cols, function(y) {x['V2'][x['V1']==y]}, USE.NAMES=TRUE))
d
        AB    AU OWN RXID
1 good boy HBGHB NLM 3233
2  bad boy HBGJI NLM 3234
```

The code you copied was written 10 years ago when the default value for stringsAsFactors was TRUE. In the current version of R (4.0.0), the default value was changed to FALSE, so anything that looks like a character will remain as a character (unless you manually change the value to TRUE in the command to read the data).